# "Общество взволновано" — удваивать ли Н?

Tags: прилагательные, причастия, удвоенные-согласные

Как правильно: общество взволновано или взволнованно?

Comment: Злата, постарайтеь пожалуйста, давать вопросам более конкретные заголовки. В Вашем случае, например, *Общество взволноваНо или взволноваННо?*, *"Общество взволновано" — удваивать ли Н?* и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: **общество взволновано.**

Это краткое причастие.

ВЗВОЛНОВАТЬ,  взволнованный; -ван, -а, -о; св.  кого-что. Привести в состояние волнения; встревожить. В. родных. Событие всех взволновало. Ветер взволновал море (книжн.).

Какие-то события  взволновали общество, ***общество взволновано***.

Краткое причастие:

1) обозначает признак по действию; 2) имеет прямое, а не переносное  значение; 
3)  можно **подобрать** зависимое слово в Т. п. со значением производителя или орудия действия.

Также: **люди взволнованы** (эти сообщением), **море взволновано** (ветром).

Сравнить: ***Лица людей взволнованны***. (**Лицо нельзя взволновать, значение переносное**).
Это краткое прилагательное:

1) обозначает качественный признак, отвечает на вопрос каков. 
2) имеет переносное, а не прямое  значение; 
3) можно заменить синонимичным прилагательным; 
4) возможны однородные отношения с другими прилагательными:

**Говорить взволнованно** – это наречие.

**Пример из Розенталя**: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62 (**пусть учитель посмотрит**)

Мировая общественность была **взволнована** сообщениями о гибели космонавтов.
Игра актёра была **проникновенна и взволнованна**.

Comment: Чем игра актера отличается от общества? Почему игра актера – взволнованна, а общество – всегда *только* взволновано? А девушка может быть взволнованна? Ясно, что может. А общество – не может? ерунда. Фактическая ошибка, поэтому минус.

Comment: 1) Вы можете взволновать лицо, игру, речь? Думаю, что нет. Значит, здесь переносное значение, это прилагательное (НН). 2) Общество, в том числе девушка, взволнованы известием. Это явное причастие (Н). 3) А если нет переносного значения и слова в Т.п. тоже нет, то что это? Если судить по частотности написания, то в современном языке вопрос  решается в пользу причастия (ведь признак по действию присутствует), хотя некоторые авторы видят здесь качественный признак (прилагательное).

Comment: Полагаться на частный выбор неудобно, поэтому даже в целях единообразного написания желательно прийти к одному решению. В Нацкорпусе частотность причастия (Н) значительно выше прилагательного (НН).

Comment: >> *...поэтому даже в целях единообразного написания желательно прийти к одному решению* Ну что вы... Раненый и раненный, воспитана и воспитанна и т.д. и т.п. - сотню примеров можно придумать. В них тоже единообразие необходимо? А ссылаться на частотность в Нацкорпусе - это уж совсем... О чем она говорит, частотность? Да, причастие встречается чаще. И что?

Comment: Парных вариантов, может быть, не сотни, но действительно много. Речь идет о причастиях и отпричастных прилагательных, для которых  полные формы имеют одинаковое написание (НН), а краткие формы пишутся по-разному (раненный/раненый к этой группе не относятся).  Эти парные варианты решаются по стандартному образцу и особых трудностей не вызывают Здесь же речь идет о конкретном глаголе ВЗВОЛНОВАТЬ, семантика которого  не так проста (там приходится различать три варианта, как я уже писала в ответе). Поэтому  в одних и тех же конструкциях пользователи могут писать Н или НН, в этом нет единообразия.

Answer (score 2):

*Общество взволновано происшествием*. Краткое причастие.

*Общество нынче (каково?) взволнованно.* Краткое прилагательное.

Comment: Сейчас я спросила у своего учителя по русскому языку. Так вот, общество взволнованно будет писаться ВСЕГДА С 2 Н! Это отглагольное прилагательное. а вот, например, море взволновано - это другое дело. Это причастие. ( всё это я пишу, не чтобы повыпендриваться, а чтобы, те, кто просматривал мою страницу, задумались и написали правильно).

Comment: Спросите учителя прямо сейчас, чем общество отличается от моря. )

Comment: Общество нынче взволнованно. Наречие, вроде.

Comment: Ну какое там наречие... Каково? - взволнованно. Краткое прилагательное. Наречие - слово неизменяемое, а как мы скажем, если девушка выглядит взволнованной? Она взволнованна, краткое прилагательное.

Answer (score 2):

Написание Н и НН в в формах глагола *взволновать (взволнованна* ― прилагательное и *взволнована* ― причастие) **всегда отличалось нестабильностью**, хотя в настоящий момент **частотность употребления причастия (Н) значительно выше.**

В Нацкорпусе: *она взволнована* ― **392 примера**, *она взволнованна* ― **20 примеров** (в основном из старых текстов).

**Чем это можно объяснить?**

Фактически мы имеем дело **с тремя ситуациями**: 1) она взволнована известием (причастие **при наличии** зависимого слова в Т.п.); 2) она грустна и взволнованна  (причастие без зависимого слова со значением "**встревожена, обеспокоена"**; 3) речь ее взволнованна (прилагательное с **переносным значением)**

Наибольшие трудности возникают во втором варианте, **но и эта форма все чаще относится к причастию.** Выражения "взволнованна чем-то" и "взволнована, встревожена, обеспокоена" различаются по значению, но всё-таки **выражают признак как действие** даже при наличии наречий степени (очень).

*Это известие очень взволновало ее. ― Она очень взволнована*.   Наречие степени *очень* относится и к глаголу, и к причастию.

А вот при наличии **синонимичных прилагательных или причастий** чаще используется одна форма (два прилагательных или два причастия): Она *грустна и взволнованна (=неспокойна)*. ― Она *встревожена и взволнована*.

(Пожалуй, это единственный случай в современном языке, когда **допускается использовать форму прилагательного,** так как он имеет объяснение).

**Примеры:**

**Причастие:**

Мать осталась сидеть над немытой посудой не потому, что была **сильно взволнована** или ее огорчило признание сына...[Людмила Петрушевская. Случай богородицы (1995)]

Движения мамы легкие, гибкие, она я**вно взволнована**, может быть самой своей миссией милосердия ...[Фазиль Искандер. Сандро из Чегема (Книга 3) (1989)]

Жить под таким наблюдением было невыносимо тяжело, но приходилось выходить к этим людям и говорить: «Я **взволнована, горда и счастлива»**. [Василий Песков, Борис Стрельников. Земля за океаном (1977)]

**Прилагательное:**

Патриция **взволнованна**, несколько раз принимается плакать, но через минуту уже смеется. [Василий Катанян. Прикосновение к идолам (1998)]

Луша тотчас вошла в комнату. Она была **бледна и взволнованна**.  [А. Е. Зарин. Казнь (1902)]